# How to update specific widget after got response from listening socket.on?

Tags: flutter, socket.io, flutter-provider

I have 2 separate class, Class Socketio and Class HomePage.
I want update HomePage after socket.on in class Socketio got response,
how to update widget in HomePage from class Socketio?

I try using provider library but didn't how to use Listenable provider

```dart
socket.on('chat message', (data) => {
    print("got reply chat"),
    setState(()) {}; // THIS setState not working because I try to separate socket class with UI widget
});
```

So how to trigger setState a specific widget / page from a class?

Comment: flutter sdk does not have `Socketio` class - so what `Socketio` class are you talking about?

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/adhara_socket_io

Comment: and you are using `on(String eventName, SocketEventListener listener)` method?

Comment: I  update the question.
I'm using method `socket.on(String eventName, (dataResponse) => {});`

Comment: so use [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html) and [StreamController](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-async/StreamController-class.html) for example

Comment: do you have example for using StreamBuilder than can listen if socketio class got something from socket.on?

Comment: i already sent you a link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html

Comment: It's hard to understand from that link

Comment: you have the video explaining that: `"Widget of the Week"` - also there is a lot of articles- tried `google("flutter streambuilder")`?

Comment: I alredy try it, it give me error. String can't be assigned to type stream.
`StreamBuilder<Chat> builder = new StreamBuilder(
            stream: Provider.of<Chat>(context).sender,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              return Text(snapshot.data?.toString() ?? 'Foo');
            },
          ),`

Comment: what is `Provider.of<Chat>(context).sender`?

Comment: It's a Provider from provider library https://pub.dev/packages/provider.
In the bottom of the provider library page, there is an StreamProvider.

with that, I can keep update Chat object after got response from socket.on (so Chat.sender always keep changing after got new chat).

But I want to update the widget by rebuild not only the value

Comment: so use `ValueListenableProvider` or `StreamProvider` - its up to you how you do that - if you dont know how to use `Provider` library so why you use it anyway? maybe use `StreamBuilder` instead?

Comment: Because I don't know how to use StreamBuilder and I use Provider for another usage, but glad, I'm already got it. Although I don't know if this is the right way how to do it. I will update my question with my answer.

Comment: ok, so as i said: use `ValueListenableProvider` or `StreamProvider` - if i had to use that library  i would use `ValueListenableProvider` and `ValueNotifier`

Comment: Thanks for the recommedation, but I already got the headache so I will stick with StreamProvider for the solution that already working although it's feels weird.

Comment: what feels weird?

Comment: I solved it by hard coded.
as initial value, I give Chat.sender = "blank",
and I keep check it if not blank so must be another new message.
the code in the answer.

then inside model I have method detectNewChat that will update the widget

Answer (score 0):

```dart
        children: <Widget> [
          (Provider.of<Chat>(context).sender == "blank")
              ? Container()
              : model.detectNewChat(widget.roomId, Provider.of<Chat>(context)),
          Expanded(child: ListView(
            children: model.chats
                .map((chat) => ChatItem(chat, Provider.of<User>(context).id)).toList(),
          ),),
          new Divider(height: 1.0),
```

I'm solved it by using Provider.of(context).
here code in my socket.io

```dart
  StreamController<Chat> chatController = StreamController<Chat>();

    socket.on('chat message', (data) => {

        print("got reply chat"),
        chatController.add(new Chat(data['roomId'], data['username'], "1123", data['message'], DateTime.now())),
    });
```

inside model

```dart
  Widget detectNewChat(String currentRoomId, Chat newChat) {
    print(newChat.sender + " "+newChat.body);
    // TODO add filter if roomId not match with current room id
    if (currentRoomId == newChat.roomId) {
      addChat(newChat.roomId, newChat);
    }
    return Container();
  }

  addChat(String roomId, Chat chat) {
    setState(ViewState.Busy);

    _socketio.emitNewChat(roomId, chat.body);

    this.chats.add(chat);
    _isComposingMessage = false;
    _textEditingController.clear();

    setState(ViewState.Idle);
  }
```

So if there is a new reply, I can just call chatController.add(newChat).

because StreamProvider from Provider library will keep getting the last value.